# Using orderby with the wordpress loop

Tags: wordpress, post, loops, sql-order-by

Have been trying to get the orderby part of my query functioning for a while now, but it seems like it is just being completely ignored.

I have a custom field in my custom post type called accordion_order. It represents the position it should show up within the loop. Ie, if 1 is input, the post will be at the top of the list, and if 1000 is entered, show at the bottom.

Here is my code :

```
$course_loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post_type_name_here', 'posts_per_page' => 0, 'orderby'=> 'accordion-order', 'order' => 'desc' ) );
```

All help appreciated,

Regards,
Dave

EDIT :::

Stackoverflow wouldn't let me add this as an answer, so if anyone could do it for me and i'll vote it up, i'd appreciated it.

Fixed it using the following code :

```
$course_loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post_type_name_here', 'posts_per_page' => 0, 'meta_key' => 'accordion-order', 'orderby'=> 'meta_value_number', 'order' => 'desc' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer by Dave O Dwyer**

(Fixed it using the following code) :

```
$course_loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post_type_name_here', 'posts_per_page' => 0, 'meta_key' => 'accordion-order', 'orderby'=> 'meta_value_number', 'order' => 'desc' ) );
```

Comment: EDIT: Upon looking at the above, it turns out that it is not in fact working. Would anyone have any ideas?

Cheers, 
Dave

Comment: orderby should be "meta_value_num", not "meta_value_number". (As of Wordpress 3.5.1. I don't know about older versions.)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn'T it be like this:

```
$course_loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post_type_name_here', 'posts_per_page' => 0, 'meta_key' => 'accordion-order', 'orderby'=> 'meta_value', 'order' => 'desc' ) );
```

changed meta_value_number to meta_value.